# Just open the Cygwin Emacs frame without black terminal window

Tags: emacs, terminal, console, cygwin

Having added the Cygwin bin directory to the `PATH`, I can launch Cygwin Emacs directly from a "Run Command" (Windows + R) window.

However, typing `emacs-w32` open first a black terminal window and then the W32 Cygwin Emacs app.

How is it possible to open just the Cygwin Emacs window?

Alternatives such as `emacs-nox` and `emacsclient-w32` don't provide the necessary answer...

Comment: The black terminal is a windows console. hiding it require a 3rd software.

Comment: Which 3rd software is required?  Isn't there any solution where the console  disappears when it "forks" Emacs?

Answer (score 3):

Use the cygwin command `run`:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\run emacs-w32
```

As you have the location of `emacs-w32` in your `PATH`, it's also the location of `run`, so you can use the following:

```
run emacs-w32
```

From that, you can then create a shortcut on your desktop, or you can pin it to your taskbar, and so on.

Comment: If I pin this shortcut to the taskbar, each click launches a new Emacs instance instead of the pinned shortcut becoming the icon for the running Emacs window. Is there a way to fix that, so that the shortcut behaves like any other pinned shortcut?